# How to remove citations when launching bash?

Tags: bash

Every time I launch `bash`, I get greeting sentences like these before the prompt:

> My cup hath runneth'd over with love.
>
> Flugg's Law:
> When you need to knock on wood is when you realize
> that the world is composed of vinyl, naugahyde and aluminum.
>
> Honk if you hate bumper stickers that say "Honk if ..."
>
> With reasonable men I will reason; with humane men I will plead; but
> to tyrants I will give no quarter.
> -- William Lloyd Garrison

How can I disable this (useful) feature?

Neither in `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` nor in `~/.bash_profile` files I have anything in that regard.

Comment: Perhaps the `~/.profile`?

Comment: Those aren't the only files bash reads, particularly as a login shell. See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: @StephenKitt - I am using Artix Linux (Arch derivative).

Comment: @K-att- - I have a `.bash_profile` file, which simply redirects to `.bashrc`. I have no `.profile` file.

Comment: @glennjackman - It is not a login shell. It happens every time I open a `bash` console.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "bash console". Terminal applications typically have a setting that allows the shell to be opened as a login shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. In my distro (Artix) it is here:

/etc/bash/bashrc.d/local.bashrc

I commented out the line with the `fortune` command, and no more famous sentences are shown when I open a console.

In case I need some fortune, I can still run the `fortune` command manually...